# Escaping org-mode example block inside of an example block

Tags: org-mode

If I am writing about emacs org-mode in an org-mode document, how do I properly escape examples.  e.g.

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE 
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE 
* This is a heading
#+END_EXAMPLE
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

should show

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE  
* This is a heading
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

but I need to escape the #+END_EXAMPLE somehow.  I'm not finding it in the manual.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi think you should use `#begin_src org`, since you want to write Org-Mode snippets.

```
#+begin_src org
  ,#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE  
  ,* This is a heading
  ,#+END_EXAMPLE
#+end_src
```

You can easily edit those snippets with `M-x` `` `org-edit-special' `` `RET` or `C-c '`.

Comment: This really is the correct solution, as highlighting works and the editing in org-mode is really helpful.

Comment: This is the first time I've learned about escaping some Org-specific syntax with `,`. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 4):

If the examples are short, you should be able to export them successfully using the alternate form for examples ([Literal Examples](http://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-examples.html))

```
: #+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
: * This is a headline
: #+END_EXAMPLE
```

Shows the expected

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
* This is a heading
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Of course if your examples are significantly longer this will not be nearly as convenient. Hopefully you'll only need to escape the #+END_EXAMPLE in short use cases (or use rectangle insert I suppose)

---

**EDIT:**

After a bit more testing, you can actually suppress commands on individual lines which will allow for longer example cases.

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
* This is a headline
,#+END_EXAMPLE
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

Will export as the expected

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
* This is a heading
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

It will also allow for manual indentation of example blocks, if you require more indentation within the block.

Comment: Awesome!  The ":" is perfect. But, how would I escape the #+END_EXAMPLE if I just wanted to do that?

Comment: @Kurt I tried just : #+END_EXAMPLE both in and out of the block. If I did it outside the block I ended up with 2 blocks exported, if I did it within the block it exported the ": " as well.

Comment: @Kurt Actually using ,#+END_EXAMPLE works. Comma also allows for manual indentation of lines. Solution edited to incorporate